# Homotopy motivation

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Currently, I am working on homotopy. I know the definition of homotopy.
Homotopy is nothing but "continuously deformation" of object.
Therefore we can say triangle and circle are same.
The concept of homotopy is published by L.E.J. Brouwer (1881-1996), he made precise many of the ideas of Henri Poincarè.

I want to know the motivation of **Homotopy**.
Why we need it?
I look out on wikipedia but I didn't find something related to it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy Incidentally, the triangle and circle are the same in topology, no need for homotopy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one reason it turns out to be useful. I won't attempt to be exhaustive, and hopefully other people will also contribute some more ideas.

By construction homotopy is a much coarser invariant than homeomorphism: two spaces which are homeomorphic are trivially homotopy equivalent. On the other hand homotopy does not even preserve basic topological invariants like dimension ($\mathbb{R}^n\simeq\ast$, for instance). While this makes it less appealing to the topologist, the upshot is that homotopy type is generally much easier to compute than homeomorphism type.

However homotopy often turns out to contain exactly the information which is needed in practice. Often difficult topological and geometric problems can be reduced to homotopy-theoretic ones. Once this is done the door is opened for algebraic-topological methods to enter the picture, and there may be pleasant consequences.

For example surfaces are classified by their homotopy type (in fact by their $H_1$'s). As another example, in light of Perelman's solution of the Poincaré conjecture, given a homology 3-sphere, the difficult geometric question of deciding whether it is $S^3$ or not is reduced to the much easier question of calculating its fundamental group.

As a slightly deeper example there are applications to 4-dimensional topology. For example Freeman-Milnor-Whitehead say that two simply connected closed topological 4-manifolds which are homotopy equivalent and share a Kirby-Siebenman invariant, are in fact homeomorphic.

Finally it would be remiss not to mention the [Borel conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_conjecture). This asserts that the homeomorphism type of a closed aspherical manifold should be completely determined by its homotopy type. While many special cases of the conjecture have been proved, its full solution is still an open problem.